# Pass parameter to cursor.execute in Django

Tags: django, django-views, pyodbc

I have the following view definition Django

```
def getEiNumberByFeatures(request):
    # request should be ajax and method should be GET.
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
        # get the nick name from the client side.
        id = request.GET.get("id", None)

    sqlQuery = """SELECT names 
                  FROM Costumer 
                  WHERE id = %s """
    cursor.execute(sqlQuery, (id))
    eiNumbers = cursor.fetchall()
    context = {"EiNumber": eiNumbers}
    return JsonResponse(context, status=200)
```

I am getting the following error

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Have somebody any idea why this can happens? Even when I am sending the parameter

Comment: Why are you not using ORM?

Comment: I think `(id)` should be `(id,)`. But @ArakkalAbu raises a good question.

Comment: thxs I found the nswer

Comment: could you please post the answer you have found ?

Answer (score 0):

first is necessary to convert to JSON Serializer

```
for ei in eiNumbers:
    data.append(list(ei))
context = {"EiNumber": data}
```